# Swift ScrollView what gesture is called when scrolling is ended if the contentSize is equal to the frameSize?

Tags: swift, uikit

I can't figure out a solution. I have a UIScrollView, and on each scroll towards right, I will increase the contentSize of the scrollView and add a View at that place. The problem is I have managed to save the last content offset by delegation when scrollview start dragging but I don't understand which delegate method to use for measuring where the gesture stopped. If I use scrollViewDidEndDecelerating, will be called immediately after the scrollViewWillBeginDragging because the content is settled to the same size of the frame.
Does anybody have any solution on it?

Comment: How about `scrollViewDidEndDragging`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619436-scrollviewdidenddragging

Comment: Problem scrolling stops immediately upon touch up if the contentSize of the scrollView is equal to the scrollview.frame.